# How to update/detect increased storage volume size /w Linux

Tags: linux, centos, storage

I have upgraded my storage and increased the size of total volume. When I check the extended size in storage management page (MSA2040), it shows everything is alright and its extended.

But when I check from my OS, it still shows the old value.

Size before upgrade was 9.4 TB, size after upgrade is 13.2 TB.

When i `df -h`, result is;

```
/dev/sdb                 9.4T  8.4T  1.1T  90% /msa10tb
```

But when I also list it via `parted /dev/sdb print free` ;

```
Model: HP MSA 2040 SAN (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 13.2TB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags:

Number  Start  End     Size    File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  13.2TB  13.2TB  xfs
```

It seems new size is not allocated. How could I allocate and update the size safely? Should I use GParted Live to fix this issue or is there anything you'd recommend me to do?

My OS is `Centos 7.4`.

Thanks in advance!

***Edit - Regarding to @ewwwhite's answer;***

```
fdisk -l /dev/sdb

Disk /dev/sdb: 13180.0 GB, 13179975368704 bytes, 25742139392 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 1048576 bytes
```

Comment: What's the output of `fdisk -l /dev/sdb` ?

Comment: @ewwhite Output added :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to grow the XFS filesystem.

In this case, `xfs_growfs /msa10tb` should work.

Comment: Is it safe to do it right away to should I completely stop I/O operations first?

Comment: Yes, the man page would show this. It's an "online resize" and can be done without downtime. You're not using partitions, so you can just run the command I specified in the answer.

Comment: I just went ahead right after you mentioned it's safe and worked like a charm, thanks! Next time I should read man page carefully :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use *growpart* utility to resizing the disk.

Exact steps for CentOS are:

```
$ yum install cloud-utils-growpart
$ growpart /dev/[DEVICE_ID] [PARTITION_NUMBER]
$ xfs_growfs /dev/[DEVICE_ID][PARTITION_NUMBER]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Yugendra, same question as above, is it safe with just stoppingthe i/o operations? Or should I do this with being extra cautious?

Comment: As you are increasing only 4G, it will be quick and will not create any problem but it is always better to take precautions. Also, you should try it on your test system first to get some hands on.

Comment: It looks like the partition has already been resized, but you might need to run `partprobe /dev/sdb` to make sure the kernel is aware of the new partition size. Then it's time for `xfs_growfs`. The XFS filesystem is designed to be on-line extendable, and in fact can be extended *only* while mounted.